# Polygon Triangle with Curved Hypotenuse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, polygon

I can create a polygon with the following XAML:

```
<Polygon Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Fill="{StaticResource GreenBrush}"
         Points="0,1 1,1 1,0"
         Stretch="Fill" />
```

This results in a right angled triangle with a straight hypotenuse.However I would like a curved hypotenuse. Is this possible using a Polygon? if not how might I accomplish the goal?

The XAML above gives the left hand triangle, but I would like something aking to the right hand triangle.

I have a feeling that this might be quite simple but I just cant seem to figure it out

[image]

- WPF
- C#
- Visual Studio 2012

Comment: A polygon won't be your solution for this since it's looking to interpolate between fixed points and you're requiring what looks like a bezier curve so you'll want to look at using Path geometry with something like a QuadraticBezierSegment for your curve, kind of like @BogdanBanciu shows in his example he grabbed from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is since Polygon will allow only straight lines achieving a curve effect would be difficult
You have two options
1)Use Blend to Create Path
eg

```
<Path Data="M0.037120935,318.97711 L3.0000002,319 0,319 z M517,5.0000003 L517,319 3.0000002,319 C286.87436,319 517,178.4174 517,5.0000003 z M517,0 L517,5.0000003 516.89777,0.063097671 z" Fill="#FFFB0404" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

2)create the triangle first and overlap its hypotenuse  with an ellipse.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Polygon         
         Points="0,1 1,1 1,0"
         Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF69FB04" />
        <Ellipse Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="628" Margin="-511,-309,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1028"/>
        </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: This is a great answer and is very clear. The other answer was also good but the clarity of this one gives the edge

Comment: @StevenWood Glad was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you :)

[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465055.aspx)

**UPDATE:**

Ok so this code :

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="326" Margin="167,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter" Background="#FFC7C5C5">
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="200,150" Point2="300,100" />                                            
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <LineSegment Point="10,300"></LineSegment>
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,300">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <LineSegment Point="300,100"></LineSegment>
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

will make this figure:
[image: here]